# Clarification on Apple in-house app development and deployment

Tags: ios, apple-developer, in-house-distribution, apple-business-manager

I've been tasked with the development and distribution of an in-house application for my organisation, I currently have an Apple Developer account and the app is going to be distributed to roughly 20 devices and my company already has Apple Business Manager as well Miradore, but I'm unsure as to how I'm meant to provision, sign, and distribute the app.

When going to deploy and app through Miradore I'm told I need an Apple Developer Enterprise Account, but when I check Apple's Enterprise webpage it advises me that I most likely **DON'T** need an enterprise account and that a regular Developer Account will *generally* be sufficient.

Additionally, correct me if I'm mistaken, but when distributing you're meant to upload it to apple for review before you're able to deploy the app either publicly or internally which puts it on the App Store / the Unlisted App Store.

I've found conflicting documentation so I'm not entirely sure which path I'm supposed to be taking, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you have an enterprise account you can sign and distribute the app directly without Apple Review or the App Store but Apple doesn't encourage this approach any more.  In App Store Connect you can mark your app as a "custom app" in the availability screen and you enter your company's Apple Business Manager id. You then upload the app from Xcode and go through Apple Review like normal. Once approved the app won't be visible on the App Store but  in Apple Business Manager you can "purchase" your app and use miradore to distribute it to the devices

Comment: Watch https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10667 and https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/304

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 ! The second video in particular helped clear a lot up